# Debian 10 installation. Display resolution stuck at single default monitor 720x400

Tags: display

Fresh install of Deb 10.
ATI RADEON 3000 on board GPU
I installed this with a really cheap/small AOC monitor via a VGA connect.  I do not know if this had anything to do with my problem.

I connected the PC to a TCL ROKU UHD TV via HDMI cable.  I logged in and started GNOME.
The resolution was like it was on the tiny console I did the install from.
When I do xrandr : 720x400 0.00+ only is displayed.
I have read, it feels like, every blog in this solar system.  Tried all of the suggestions.
I did go to GRUB command mode and listed all display capabilities and they were all in the output.
I checked the driver level.
Manually added another resolution and attempted to switch to it.  It failed with "Max level is 720x400 0.00"
I also get the famous "xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default" message.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Best regards,
Michael:D

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  Removed the DVD/CD reference in the apt sources list.  I watched an obscure  youtube video in Russian.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pj5A3FX9rQg

I feel very dumb right now...